# Проблемы с кодировкой (кириллица)

Tags: java

Делаю простую программку по локализации. Написала файл doctor_ru.properties в кодировке UTF-8. 
В файле следующая информация:

```
title=Список врачей
name=Имя
surname=Фамилия
sec=Отчество
area=Должность
```

При запуске на сервере кодировка сбрасывается, и получается такой вот результат. Прошу совета, что можно сделать. Прилагаю фото.

Основной код:

```
package spb.hospital;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/doctors")
public class doctors extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public doctors() { 
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String lang = req.getParameter("lang");
        if(lang==null) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, "Ожидался параметр lang");
            return;
        }
        if(!"en".equalsIgnoreCase(lang)&&!"ru".equalsIgnoreCase(lang)) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, "lang принимает только 'en' или 'ru'");
            return;
        }
        ResourceBundle res=ResourceBundle.getBundle("doctor","en".equalsIgnoreCase(lang)?Locale.ENGLISH:Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println(getServletContext().getInitParameter("wday"));
        req.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String surname = req.getParameter("surname");
        String sec=req.getParameter("sec");
        String area = req.getParameter("area");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        try {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head><title>"+res.getString("title")+"</title></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<table border='2'>");
            out.println("<tr><td><b>"+res.getString("surname")+"</td></b><td><b>"+res.getString("name")+"</td></b><td><b>"+res.getString("sec")+"</td></b>"
                    + "<td><b>"+res.getString("area")+"</td></b></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td>"+(surname!=null?surname:"-")+"</td><td>"+(name!=null?name:"-")+"</td><td>"
                    +(sec!=null?sec:"-")+"</td><td>"+(area!=null?area:"-")+"</td></tr>");
            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request,response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request,response);
    }

}
```

[Результат на сервере](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiGjU.png)

Кодировки везде стоят UTF-8, но сам сервер почему-то игнорирует при получении запроса.

Comment: Гадание без кода. Дорого. +7(111)111-11-11. Пророк Алексей

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, пожалуйста

Comment: Гадайте с кодом :)
Прошу прощения, просто сомневаюсь, что он играет роль здесь.

Comment: Вставила основной метод, в котором работаю.

Comment: Код изображением - ещё дороже.

Comment: Первый раз спрашиваю))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing

Comment: Это по идее в файле server. xml должно быть, но у меня такого нет, я предварительно прописала 
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
  useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
Вроде бы разницы нет особо, русский отображался нормально до попыток локализации.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте проработать вопрос с Фильтрами

```java
@WebFilter("/*")
public class EncodingFilter extends HttpFilter {

 private static final String UTF = "utf-8";

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

               request.setCharacterEncoding(UTF);
               response.setCharacterEncoding(UTF);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Также обратите внимание на тип кодировки в служебном заголовке вашей ***.html*** или **.jsp**

Comment: Это проблему не решило, пробовала раскомментировать web.xml строки с фильтрами, тоже бесполезно. Бред какой-то, что в eclipse, что в idea.